# Unexpected type error in interaction of type narrowing and `Extract` helper with generic type

Tags: typescript

I'm puzzled by the following problem. I have a simple tagged union:

```
type MyUnion = 
    | { tag: "Foo"; field: string; } 
    | { tag: "Bar"; } 
    | null;
```

And now I have this generic function:

```
const foo = <T extends MyUnion>(value: T) => {
    // Narrowing works as expected.
    if (value === null) { return; }
    const notNull: NonNullable<T> = value;

    // Narrowing works with field access, but not with `Extract` type.
    if (value.tag !== "Foo") { return; }
    const s: string = value.field;  // Field can be accessed -> all good here.
    const extracted: Extract<T, { tag: "Foo" }> = value;  // error!
};
```

([**Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCqA7Alge0VAvFAUFfUAPlAN5TACGA5gFxQBEAYqqvQNxQBmyEANgCZ0AzsABOyRFQ4BfXASKly1OvQBCFUeyiy8BYogCuvXmxw4AxuhFcWWKAB4AKlAgAPYBET8hsBCnQAfAAUAG4UvAYQdI4AlFgBpLr4APTJUAByGqKoAO4SVFA5qKIA1j4UPm6Q5h78AHRJUMicUKHhkViY2IbGcWSiEMAGoogyjZaI1oiowOlGvHTp6HPGFABGvBBOCdhhERCmjakZWbn5hcVlhcjAABZcPAJQFObmEEJCADRQawbAUNN-nk7lAAAYAUXcohewFB5HAEAa8marT2kTqlAKAEIugxmKw+lABkMRmN5BNrEJhGJzrt2ojuHx+BwoMdGI9+FBzBQMGtoC9Xu8hBB+N8hKgAac8pILqUhEiCBT-m4xDCRXRIaqak5vmRMSp8fRtDsoGiDjhpGwgA))

The last line results in this error:

```
Type 'T & {}' is not assignable to type 'Extract<T, { tag: "Foo"; }>'.
```

And I really can't understand why. Writing it outside the function without the generic as `Extract<MyUnion, { tag: "Foo" }>` results in exactly the correct type. What's going on here?

*Note*: in my real code, the function has another parameter callback: (v: Extract<T, { tag: "Foo" }>) => void. And calling that callback leads to the same type error. So my goal is to somehow make this work: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCqA7Alge0VAvFAUFfUAPlAN5TACGA5gFxQBEAYqqvQNxQBmyEANgCZ0AzsABOyRFQ4BfXASKly1OvQBCFUeyiy8BYogCuvXmxw4AxuhFcWWKAB4AKlAgAPYBET8hsBCnQAfAAUuvgAbhS8BhB0jgA0cgTmkbwARhTmANZ0QWF0AKLuohnATglklLQMzKzaAQCUWAFQYajI-HE4jZjNJKFQAPQDUAByGqKoAO4SVFCTqKKZPhQ+bpDmHvwAdP3InFC5kdFYmNiGxo1kohDABqKIMv2WiNaIqMAjRrx0I+ifxhRUrwIE5mtgIlEIKZ+kNRuMpjM5gslnNkMAABZcHgCKAZcwQIRCBKpAzAKBvMnTDFQAAGhTEJRp5HAEB28j2Bwh0S2lSgAEJTtUWPRLlBrrd7o95MljOksodIfVTNJTEA). So the function `foo` basically performs specific checks on a value, handles special cases somehow, and then calls the callback with the sanitized value. I would assume TypeScript somehow allows me to express this kind of abstraction?

Comment: Probably, or just add that explanation to the question, since otherwise it's not clear why you wouldn't want to just use `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be seen as a design limitation in TypeScript. This issue is that `Extract` is a conditional type which depends on a generic type `T`.

`T` is pretty much unspecified at the point in code where you are using the conditional. Sure, `T` has a constraint which forces it to be a subtype of `MyUnion`. But no *concrete* type is known yet because it is specified by the caller of the function. Whenever the compiler encounters a conditional type like that, it is unable to evaluate it. The type stays essentially opaque to a point where *only* values of type `Extract<T, { tag: "Foo" }>` can be safely assigned to it.

You can find disussions of similar issues in [#33484](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33484) or [#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884). There are lots of situations regarding generics and conditionals where the typing may be sound to a human reading the code but where the compiler stops reasoning because of yet unresolved types.

---

You may be wondering why this works:

```
const notNull: NonNullable<T> = value;
```

[#49119](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49119) changed `NonNullable` from a *conditional type* to one which simply intersects `T` with `{}`.

```
- type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;
+ type NonNullable<T> = T & {};
```

The same PR also introduced improvements to control flow anaylsis. Checking if a variable with a generic type is not `null` would intersect the type of the variable with `{}`.

This makes assignability possible since both `NonNullable<T>` and the type of `value` evaluate to `T & {}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know I just asked "what's going on here?" in my original post, but do you have any hints how one might work around this limitation? (Also see my edit or the comments below my original post, in case you haven't yet). Thanks!

Comment: could you share a playground containing this callback?

Comment: Sure! See my latest edit above.

Comment: Is this the intentional behavior? If you call `foo` like this: `foo({ tag: "Bar" }, (c) => {})` then `c` would have the `never` type. If this is what you want, you will have to use a type assertion when calling `callback` like `callback(value as Extract<T, { tag: "Foo" }>);`

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Thanks, type assertion it is then. Should have put the callback in my question from the very start, but oh well. Thank you for your explanation and assistance!